# Can you 'compile' html files together to simulate a 'include' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, compilation, include

I love SASS for the reason you can create mixins and re-use your code by including various SASS files which compile upon export/save (depending on your application). PHP can do somewhat the same, but I've never seen one HTML page broken into various HTML files and compiled to one whole upon export/save.

I can't write PHP and I don't want that overhead just to make things easier and having to adjust one files (i.e. 'navigation.html') instead of changing code in every page on the site.

Therefor I'm asking either one of the following two:

1. A compiler, such as [Codekit](https://codekitapp.com), that can merge parts of HTML files together
2. A HTML/Javascript/jQuery/Ajax (<- No experience with, please guide) function to include HTML parts together upon load

Having to adjust one thing over 50 pages across can be a pain, but having the same code on each can also serve some uniformity and create assurance. That's why I was hoping there was a solution to my request.

Comment: According to my knowledge  its not simply possible in HTML, until you use js,angular or php or any other programming language . In that you can create a common section in a separate file and then include in main file.Like you have header,footer,navigation for all pages then you can create separate file for all and then include in main file.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is what I work with, you create generic "components" and depending on things like the ID of the parent component where you insert it, it will behave in different ways or load from JS or jQuery different "function libraries" for example if the parent div of the menu component is 'mainMenu' it will call the case where the main options are displayed. When the menu component parent ID is 'load' it displays the load button and adds on it the code to load files...

page 1

```
 <div id='mainMenu'></div>
```

then page 2

```
 <div id='load'></div>
```

then jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    component = "<ul id='menu'><li></li></ul>";
    $(body).find("div").each(function(){
        switch($(this).attr("id") {
            case "mainMenu":
                code to add functionality to component;
                break;
            case "load":
                code to add functionality to component;
                break;
            default:
                code to manage error;
        }
    });
}):
```

This is just an example of what I think you could do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `w3-include-html` from [w3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp)

Example:

`<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>`

[HTML Include](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: Can you find something regarding the browser support about this? I've never read anything like this. I think up to IE 9.0 is minimum.

Comment: I couldn't find any information regarding support. It was created this year if that helps. https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_downloads.asp